# Mvc ActionLink with javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working with MVC, I have a view with an ActionLink that calls an Action of my controller, my issue is when I want to call also a javascript function on the onClick() event of that action link (as that action link converts to html standart tag on execution time). How should i do this? what is the better way? 
Here is the code of my ActionLink:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("View Report", "GeneratePdf", new { strProductId = myObject.productId})%>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give the link an id (or class) and apply the handler unobtrusively using javascript.  Example using jQuery:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("View Report", "GeneratePdf",
     new { strProductId = myObject.productId},
     new { id = "reportLink" } )%>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#reportLink').click( function() {
             ... do what you need to do...
             // return false; // to cancel the default action of the link
        });
    });
</script>
```