# Return Succes Message After Delete/Update/create

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my `GesAgence` Page action :

```
        public ActionResult GesAgence()
    {
        var test = new Models.J2VEntities();
        return View(test.agence);
    }
```

This is my Action for `Deleting` :

```
        public ActionResult DeleteAg(string id)
    {
        Models.J2VEntities entity = new Models.J2VEntities();

        Models.agence model = (from p in entity.agence
                               where p.Idag == id
                               select p).SingleOrDefault();

        //Sauvgarde ds la BD
        entity.agence.DeleteObject(model);
        entity.SaveChanges();
        return View("gesAgence");
    }
```

So i'm wondring how to return Succes message after deleting(i tried with TempData but didn't succed because my `gesAgence` must return model not `TempData`).

Comment: How are you calling this delete action? Via JavaScript/ajax or from an action link?

Comment: Html.ActionLink or  Ajax.ActionLink? One sends an Ajax request and one does a full page request. Depending on what you're doing, your options change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ajax to call your controller from your viewpage and pop up the message whatever your controller returned, try something like this.

**Script on your view page.**

```
function onDeleteAg (id) {
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete AG ?")
        if (answer) {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "Get",
                    url: '<%= Url.Action("DeleteAg","YourControllerName") %>',
                    data: { agId: id },
                    success: function (data) {                        
                        //HERE--data is the message you that your controller DeleteAg method will return after it's called. you need to do something here to display this message(data) anywhere you want to . something like below. 
                         alert(data);                          

                    },
                    error: (function () { alert("Error! Ag was not deleted." ); })
                });
        }
    };
```

**Method on your controller.**

```
public string DeleteAg(string agId)
    {
       try{

        Models.J2VEntities entity = new Models.J2VEntities();

        Models.agence model = (from p in entity.agence
                               where p.Idag == id
                               select p).SingleOrDefault();

        //Sauvgarde ds la BD
        entity.agence.DeleteObject(model);
        entity.SaveChanges();
}
       catch(Exception ex)
        {
          return "AG has not been deleted successfully;
        }

        return "AG has been deleted successfully;
    }
```

Comment: I have to change My actionLink or no?

Comment: You don't have to use actionLink. just call onDeleteAg, it's a javascript funciton. 
If you really want to use actionlink, you need to make you actionLink to call that javascript funciton. check this thread to see how. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889145/mvc-actionlink-with-javascript

Comment: Like this i call OnDeleteag :
`<input type="button" value="test" onclick="onDeleteAg(<% item.Idag %>)" />`

Comment: Yes. that's exactly you can do

Comment: thank's but can you check out your function because i get this error `CS1002: ; attendu` on input line. i think ther is some missing or added `{};()`

Comment: Can you set breakpoint on both side of view and controller to see what happened

Comment: I have made some change now it show me the confirmation message but after this nothing is happed i tried to use `(answer == true)`but didn't work.
the problem is that the ajax function didn't call my `DeleteAg` function.

Comment: I just tested it. It's working fine. 
Did you use the correct controller name in  url: '@Url.Action("DeleteAg", "YourControllerName")'? and also included the jquery library to your project?

Comment: yes i have changede `YourControllerName`. but wich one of juery library i should inculde wich file?

Comment: something is like
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Already Done, sir This ajax function jump over the `if(answer)` and show me after click Ok on message box this part `error: (function () { alert("Error! Ag was not deleted."); })`

Comment: Oke thank's no problem, you can find my mail and other information on my profile.

Comment: updated the script function to use 
url:'<%= Url.Action("DeleteAg","Home") %>'

Answer (score 0):

you can call this method via ajax and return **JsonResult** instead of **ActionResult**, by looking result you can show message to user.

```
public JsonResult DeleteAg(string id)
{
    Models.J2VEntities entity = new Models.J2VEntities();

    Models.agence model = (from p in entity.agence
                           where p.Idag == id
                           select p).SingleOrDefault();

    //Sauvgarde ds la BD
    entity.agence.DeleteObject(model);
    entity.SaveChanges();
    var json = new
            {
                success = true
            };
    return Json(json);
}
```

Comment: And what's the script i should use in my view page?

Answer (score 0):

You can set Success to ViewBag

```
  public ActionResult DeleteAg(string id)
    {
        Models.J2VEntities entity = new Models.J2VEntities();

        Models.agence model = (from p in entity.agence
                               where p.Idag == id
                               select p).SingleOrDefault();

        //Sauvgarde ds la BD
        entity.agence.DeleteObject(model);
        entity.SaveChanges();

        ViewData["Success"] = true;

        return View("gesAgence");
    }
```

in view

```
@if(ViewData["Success"] != null && (bool)ViewData["Success"]){
    <script>alert("Sucess!");</script>
}
```

This is my view :

```
    <% if(ViewData != null && ViewData["Success"] != null && (bool)ViewData["Success"]){ %>
    <script type="text/javascript"> alert("Sucess!");</script>
<% } %>
      <div class="clear">
              &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div id="main">
            <h1> Demande preinscrit</h1>
            <ul class="listing">
    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
                <li>
               <div class="listinfo">
                    <h3>
                      <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nomag) %>
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                      <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Idag) %>
                    </p>
                    <span class="price"> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Adrag) %> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vilag) %> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gov) %></span> <span class="media">Tel : <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telag) %> |</span> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mailag) %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="listingbtns">
                    <span class="listbuttons"><%: Html.ActionLink("Bloque", "Bloque", new {id= item.Idag}) %> </span>
                    <span class="listbuttons"><%: Html.ActionLink("Supprime", "DeleteAg", new { id = item.Idag })%></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear">
                    &nbsp;
                  </div>
                </li>
    <% } %>
```

i got this error : `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on this line `<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>`.

Comment: I'm using ASPX not Razor. with what i replace `Viewbag`

Comment: thank's, but in my action `DeleteAg` i have `return view("gesagence")`  and take look on `gesAgence` Action will note that i can't do this `return view(ViewData["Success"])` in my Delete Action

Comment: you dont have to return ViewData. You should just set the value. In your return View i think it is gesAgence.aspx you check the ViewData

Comment: Look this is my View page: 
`<% if(ViewData["Success"] != null && (bool)ViewData["Success"]){ %>
        <script type="text/javascript"> alert("Sucess!");</script>
    <% } %>
          //html code
        <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
                    //code
        <% } %>`
 i got this error : `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on this line `<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>`

Comment: i change view again. try one more time again. i think `ViewData` is null in first time

Comment: Delete Action it's works and redirect me to `GesAgence` page but no alert it's showin .